# react-native-fcm how to redirect on specific page after click on notification from tray

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to redirect on specific page after click on notification from tray in react-native-fcm, but unable to do so. React native fcm documentation does not have proper documentation on handling click listener

[I follow this tutorial for react-native-fcm](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm)

```
 this.notificationListener = FCM.on(FCMEvent.Notification, notif => {
  console.log("Notification recived", notif);
  if(notif.local_notification){
     console.log("Notification recived local", "local notification");

    return;
  }
  if(notif.opened_from_tray){

     console.log("Notification recived tray ", "opened from tray");

    return;
  }

  if(Platform.OS ==='ios'){
          //optional
          //iOS requires developers to call completionHandler to end notification process. If you do not call it your background remote notifications could be throttled, to read more about it see the above documentation link.
          //This library handles it for you automatically with default behavior (for remote notification, finish with NoData; for WillPresent, finish depend on "show_in_foreground"). However if you want to return different result, follow the following code to override
          //notif._notificationType is available for iOS platfrom
          switch(notif._notificationType){
            case NotificationType.Remote:
              notif.finish(RemoteNotificationResult.NewData) //other types available: RemoteNotificationResult.NewData, RemoteNotificationResult.ResultFailed
              break;
            case NotificationType.NotificationResponse:
              notif.finish();
              break;
            case NotificationType.WillPresent:
              notif.finish(WillPresentNotificationResult.All) //other types available: WillPresentNotificationResult.None
              break;
          }
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you can add whatever you want to do when the notification is clicked inside the `if(notif.opened_from_tray){}` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi everyone problem are fixed by using the setTimeout function in notification opened_from_tray block.

Sample Code

```
redirect(){ this.props.navigator.push({name:"DetailPage", data:this.state.pageData[1]}); }

`

this.notificationListener = FCM.on(FCMEvent.Notification, notif => {
console.log("Notification recived", notif);
if(notif.local_notification){
console.log("Notification recived local", "local notification");

  if(notif.opened_from_tray){

     console.log("Notification recived local ", "opened from tray");

    setTimeout(() => {

    //    console.log('setting page call!'); 
    console.log('this is props',props);
      this.redirect()
      // this.props.navigator.push({name:"Sports"});
    //  // this.props.navigator.push({name:'DetailPage',data:Data});
    }, 5000);

     //this.props.navigator.push({name:"Settings"});

  }

return;
}
if(notif.opened_from_tray){

 console.log("Notification recived tray ", "opened from tray");
 //this.props.navigator.replacePrevious({name:"Settings"});
return;
}

if(Platform.OS ==='ios'){
//optional
//iOS requires developers to call completionHandler to end notification process. If you do not call it your background remote notifications could be throttled, to read more about it see the above documentation link.
//This library handles it for you automatically with default behavior (for remote notification, finish with NoData; for WillPresent, finish depend on "show_in_foreground"). However if you want to return different result, follow the following code to override
//notif._notificationType is available for iOS platfrom
switch(notif._notificationType){
case NotificationType.Remote:
notif.finish(RemoteNotificationResult.NewData) //other types available: RemoteNotificationResult.NewData, RemoteNotificationResult.ResultFailed
break;
case NotificationType.NotificationResponse:
notif.finish();
break;
case NotificationType.WillPresent:
notif.finish(WillPresentNotificationResult.All) //other types available: WillPresentNotificationResult.None
break;
}
}`
```